# How to display two links based on the drop option selection?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, antd

I gave a simple dropdown option.Here i want to display two links based on the selection.

i add two menu options with key values,like CULT-4a and HIN-4A and i add handle click function.Now if i want to select CULT-4a display with 2 links.how to display it.Based on the selection i have to display the links.here i return the links but they are not displayed.

```
class DropOption extends React.Component {
    state = {
        visible: false,
    };

    handleMenuClick = (e) => {
        if (e.key === '1') {
          alert("cultA");
          this.setState({
            visible: true,
        })
        }
        else {
            alert("HIN");
        }
      }

    render() {
        const menu = (
            <Menu onClick={this.handleMenuClick}>
                <Menu.Item key="1">CULT-4A</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="2">HIN-4A</Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
        )
        return (
            <div align="center">
                <Dropdown
                    overlay={menu}>
                    <a className="ant-dropdown-link" href="#">
                        Select one option<Icon type="down" />
                    </a>
                  <DisplayLinks visible={this.state.visible}/>
                </Dropdown>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here i add my DisplayLink.js Component code

```
render() {
        return (
            <div align="center">
            <a href="#" onClick={this.showCourseModal}>Course</a>
            <a href="#" onClick={this.showStudentList}>StudentList</a            

        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning two link but you are not using them anywhere. 
You need to attach it to element which depends upon states or props to display

```
import React from "react"
import { Dropdown, Menu, Icon } from 'antd'

class DropOption extends React.Component {
    state = {
        visible: false,
        dropdownOptions : <a className="ant-dropdown-link" href="#">
                        Select one option<Icon type="down" />
                    </a>
    };

    handleMenuClick = (e) => {
        if (e.key === '1') {
        alert("cultA");
        this.setState({
            dropdownOptions :  <span>
            <a href="#">Course</a>
            <a href="#">StudentList</a>
        </span>
        })
        }
        else {
            alert("HIN");
        }
    }

    render() {
        const menu = (
            <Menu onClick={this.handleMenuClick}>
                <Menu.Item key="1">CULT-4A</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="2">HIN-4A</Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
        )
        return (
            <div align="center">
                <Dropdown
                    overlay={menu}>
                    this.state.dropdownOptions
                </Dropdown>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DropOption
```

Comment: based on the selection i want to display the links how to display it.

Comment: where i have to add the links and display it. i am new learner of this technology.i want display these links in a single page

Comment: will these new link be added under dropdown element ?

Comment: i have to add two links based on the selection that is selected in the dropdown. i have to think based on the key value it will display so that reason i have to add in if condition

Comment: You are handling the condition correctly but you are returning the new links to  your onClick function but it can't render it for you. You need to return your links such way that it can be rendered

Comment: i will take another component to display the links like Display links.i added that component its render like  render() {
        return (
            <div align="center">
            <a href="#" onClick={this.showCourseModal}>Course</a>
            <a href="#" onClick={this.showStudentList}>StudentList</a>
                <CourseModal
                    visible={this.state.visible}
                    onOk={this.onOk} />
                    <StudentListtable showtable={this.state.showTable} data={data}/>
                 </div>
        )
    }

Comment: i have try to edited code by i am getting this exception React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

Comment: can you add your new code by editing the question to have a better look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188606/discussion-between-laxmi-and-shadab-ahmed).